# IDE para desenvolvimento em ionic framework?

Tags: ionic

Estou procurando uma IDE para desenvolver em Ionic framework. Tentei usar o NetBeans mas não estou conseguindo instalar o plugin IonicExtension, aqui: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/59028/ionicextension

Lendo a documentação do projeto IonicExtension para Netbeans o desenvolvedor apenas diz para clonar o git e adicionar o arquivo IonicExtension no downloaded do netbeans, porem nao existe esse arquivo IonicExtension no projeto.

Qual IDE seria a melhor opção para desenvolver em Ionic Framework ?

Answer (score 1):

Eu estou utilizando o [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) e até o momento está dando conta do recado.

Comment: estou estudando com o Sublime Text 3 ...Para o VS existe plugin para desenvolvimento Ionic ?

Comment: Da pra utilizar o bower para baixar o pacote do Ionic, sem problemas. Além disso, o Visual Studio já possui plugin para o Cordova. Outra ferramenta que passei a utilizar recentemente para criar os protótipos dos meus aplicativos é o [Codepen](http://codepen.io). É bem produtivo.